# UIScrollView paging pattern

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Not sure if I used a right topic for this question or not, anyway, I want to create the paging effect that we get from UIScrollView thorough an IBAction. (By pressing that button the view pages like when we swipe left on the scroll view)

I have a client that wants me to make a flashcard thing for her, and she wants to have one flashcard in each view. I try and put all the flashcards in one scroll view and the paging was prefectly working, but I did not get the UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight effect.

I implement the flashcard effect, by basically have a hover view, and then added two subviews to that hover view, and put a button the same size of the views on top of them. It works fine when it is not in scroll view.

So do you guys have any suggestion how to implement this? Am I doing something wrong in scroll view? Is it good to actually implement the paging effect (if its's possible) through out action target?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: you can set the "setContentOffset" of the scrollView in btn action to change the View with paging effect.

Comment: you should check iCarousel project (https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
```

wont work on `UIScrollView`, usually the `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight` used for different `views` or images, but not the same `View`. so in your case the `Paging` is not useful.

I suggest you to create separated `Views` as you need, and then you can `Flip` from one to another.

hope it helps you.

Comment: say I have two views and each one of them have another 2 views, which flip like a flashcard, my question here is how can navigate between those first few (which basically are the containers) without navigating to another different view controller?

Comment: you can use this method to flip your Views:

-(void)flip
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:firstView toView:secoundView
                      duration:10.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:NULL];
}

try to implement it and see how it works ^_^

Comment: Yes, Thats what Im looking for, Thenks :)